# What is the best security practice when setting up Google Query?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, vpc, google-iam

I had some experience with the AWS but very new to Google cloud platform, especially Google Big Query. I have read many documentations, but felt a bit confused and overwhelmed by amount of the information.
    If I want to set up big query, which will be used to connect to several different third party platforms. (that uses Big query as the connector) From security standpoint (network side), what is the best practice should I follow to make sure that the data is secure in transit?

I have already set up a service account, which only has the access to Big Query. I will be assigning users who need the big query access the "service account user " role. 
From what I have read, service account's key will automatically rotate every two weeks. Does it mean the connector will break every two weeks?
If so is there a better way of making it permanent?
There is also a default VPC when I set up the project. Is there any services provided by Google Cloud platform that I should be aware to make it more secure?

Comment: If you use Google managed keys (recommended), key rotation will be handled for you.  Data is always encrypted in transit. So nothing for you to do there either.

Comment: Hi there! Welcome to SO. This is a very broad question. Lak is right however. Let Google handle the keys for you. They'll do a much better job. If you really want to however, you can manage your own keys, turn on VPC service controls, use AEAD encryption functions etc. Users shouldn't be using service accounts to access BigQuery. They should only be for local development. Service accounts should only really be used for machine'y stuff. Let users access using their own accounts for proper logging/auditing/off-boarding. Assign the appropriate IAMs/ACLs/policies to each user (use groups).

Comment: Hi, GrahamPolley & Lak Thank you very much for the response! I will use Google managed keys.  One more question regarding the service account if anyone is able to shed light upon this: Let's say one of our data scientists uses his/her own access/secret keys to pull data from BigQuery and the processes is automated with the a lot of scripts. Does it mean when he/she leaves the company, the only ways to keep the script functioning are (a. Keep his/her account active & update keys && b. Disable his account and use someone else's key) Either way won't a service account make more sense in thiscase?

Answer (score 0):

I will try to summarize what you have discussed so far and address your latest question: By default data is encrypted both at rest and in transit using Google managed keys. This is the recommended setup since you avoid complexity and your data is secure.

User accounts ([Google Accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview#google_account)) are for developers: people that would set up encryption keys, if you decide to use [customer-managed encryption keys (CMEK)](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/customer-managed-encryption) and that would interact “manually” with BigQuery, typically through the UI or the command line tool.

[Service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview#service_account), as Graham mentioned, are for machines, so scripts and automated stuff should run with service accounts.

CryptoKeys are resources in GCP, so IAM policies can and should be set on them, so any service account or user account that interacts with CryptoKeys should have the proper level of permissions. You can see the list of available permissions [here](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/reference/permissions-and-roles). For instance, to create a table in BigQuery with customer-managed keys, it is necessary to grant the [Encrypter/Decrypter role](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/customer-managed-encryption#assign_role) to the BigQuery system service account (this is a service account created by default and it is required for BigQuery to correctly work within your project).

To address your latest concern, as long as there are at least 2 users within your organization with the proper permissions to manage keys, you don’t have to worry about an employee's departure (plus, the project owner basically has all permissions over all resources). Also, the [project owner and the cloudkms.admin role](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/iam#modifying_iam_permissions) can grant permissions over Keys to other user or service accounts.